# Regex and PHP for extracting contents between tags with several line breaks

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks

How can I extract the content between tags with several line breaks?

I'm a newbie to regex, who would like to know how to handle unknown numbers of line break to match my query.

**Task: Extract content between `<div class="test">` and the first closing `</div>` tag.**

**Original source:**

```
<div class="test">optional text<br/>
content<br/>
<br/>
content<br/>
...
content<br/><a href="/url/">Hyperlink</a></div></div></div>
```

I've worked out the below regex,

```
/<div class=\"test\">(.*?)<br\/>(.*?)<\/div>/
```

Just wonder how to match several line breaks using regex.

There is DOM for us but I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Use an HTML parser instead. You'll find plenty of examples with the DOM extension here in SO.

Comment: What you mean is parsing XML with regular expressions?

Comment: Parsing is the task of processing text into useful data.  Regexen are only capable of parsing the [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), which does not include, for instance, the language of balanced brackets (where `([])()` matches, but `([)` does not).  HTML requires the ability to do things like that (*e.g.*, `<a><b></b></a>` is legal, but `<a><b></a>` is not), and so literally *cannot* be parsed with regular expressions.  You had a goal: "get at the given `div`".  However, the way you said you wanted to do it cannot possibly get you there.

Comment: I admit there are limations on handling variables and conditions by using regex. I'll try to use the native method - DOM to manipulate HTML/XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `preg_match_all('/<div class="test">(.*?)<\/div>/si', $html, $matches);`. But remember that this will match the first closing `</div>` within the HTML. Ie. if the HTML looks like `<div class="test">...aaa...<div>...bbb...</div>...ccc...</div>` then you would get `...aaa...<div>...bbb...` as the result in $matches...

So in the end using a DOM parser would indeed by a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should not parse (x)html with regular expressions. Use DOM.

I'm a beginner in xpath, but one like this should work:

```
//div[@class='test']
```

This selects all divs with the class 'test'. You will need to load your html into a DOMDocument object, then create a DOMXpath object relating to that, and call its `execute()` method to get the results. It will return a DOMNodeList object.
Final code looks something like this:

```
$domd = new DOMDocument();
$domd->loadHTML($your_html_code);
$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
$items = $domx->execute("//div[@class='test']");
```

After this, your div is in `$items->item(0)`.

This is untested code, but if I remember correctly, it should work.

**Update**, forgot that you need the content.

If you need the *text* content (no tags), you can simply call `$items->item(0)->textContent`. If you also need the tags, here's the equivalent of javascript's innerHTML for PHP DOM:

```
function innerHTML($node){
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));

  return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

Call it with `$items->item(0)` as the parameter.

Comment: I'll study your method seriously later on. Currently reading some tutorials of DOM.

Comment: @John XPath will need some getting used to, but when you start to see the power of it, you'll see that it is awesome, and a lot more useful than regexps. I recently started rewriting one of my data miner classes from regexps to dom and xpath, and I was surprised how shorter it got, and it is also quite readable, unlike the regex version.